# jQuery add border to table

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox, html-table

I'm new to jQuery, I tried this:

```
<input value="1"  type="checkbox" name="mytable" id="checkbox2"  style="float:left;"
        />

{literal}

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   //checkbox
   $(".mytable").click(function(){
    $(".mytable").toggleClass('mytableborders');

    });
});
</script>
{/literal}

<table class="mytable" id="cart">....</table>
```

But it doesn't work, I want the checkbox to change the class of the table from `.mytable` to `.mytableborders`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your checkbox id is "checkbox2". So the selector for your checkbox is `$("#checkbox2")`, and your table id is "cart" and selector is `$("#cart")`

Try

```
$("#checkbox2").click(function(){
    $("#cart").toggleClass('mytableborders');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
  $("#checkbox2").click(function(){
    $("#cart").toggleClass('mytableborders');
  });
});
```

The click event should be attached to the checkbox by ID, not name.

Answer (score 1):

Toggle class will add the class if it's not present and remove it if it is.  If you want it to swap the classes, use `addClass` and `removeClass`:

```
    $(".mytable").removeClass('mytable').addClass('mytableborders');
```